# Throw exception for a Functional Interface in kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, exception, interface

I am new to the Kotlin and now I try to migrate an app from Java to Kotlin.
I have the following interface in java

```
  public interface FunctionWithExceptions<T, R, E extends Exception> {

    R apply(T t) throws E;
  }
```

and when I translate it to Kotlin I have the following code

```
    interface FunctionWithExceptions<T, R, E : Exception?> {
        @Throws(E::class)
        fun apply(t: T): R

    }
```

but I have the following error:
Cannot use 'E' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead.
could you please let me know how to fix it

Comment: You might not be able to translate this precisely.

Comment: Note that Kotlin doesn't have checked exceptions, so this entire interface may be pointless if it's only used from Kotlin. `@Throws` is only used when calling the code from Java.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. yes this will not calling from Java then it will be pointless